# Finding average based on lag of previous weeks from current weeks in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, lag, summary

I am new to dplyr and trying to calculate the avg sales going 3 weeks back from each week of a product.If we don't have all 3 weeks historical data we will consider how many ever data points which are present.

Edit:

I am sorry I missed this earlier , but there is an additional factor which we need to consider, we should only take lag of those columns where there was no Promo.

Here is a sample data

```
df =   structure(list(Product = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Promo = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    Week = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("2017-01-01", 
    "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"), class = "factor"), 
    Sales = c(50, 50, 60, 70, 50, 50, 80, 70)), .Names = c("Product", 
"Promo", "Week", "Sales"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
  Product Promo       Week Sales
1       A     0 2017-01-01    50
2       B     0 2017-01-01    50
3       A     1 2017-01-02    60
4       A     0 2017-01-03    70
5       A     0 2017-01-04    50
6       B     1 2017-01-02    50
7       B     0 2017-01-03    80
8       A     0 2017-01-05    70
```

I want go back 3 non Promo (Flag =0) weeks for each product , so o/p would be something like this

```
     Product Promo       Week Sales  Avg_Non_Promo_Sales
1       A     0 2017-01-01    50       50
2       B     0 2017-01-01    50       50
3       A     1 2017-01-02    60       50 # We have only 1 non promo week 
                                          #before 
4       A     0 2017-01-03    70       60 #70+50 /2 
5       A     0 2017-01-04    50       56.6 #(50 + 70 + 50 /3, non promo)
6       B     1 2017-01-02    50       50
7       B     0 2017-01-03    80       65 #50 + 80 /2
8       A     0 2017-01-05    70       60 # 240/4
```

Comment: Have a look at `library(zoo); rollapply(...)`

Comment: As @Sotos stated, may be `with(df, ave(Sales, Product, FUN = function(x) rollapplyr(x, 4, mean, partial = TRUE)))`

Comment: @Sotos , could you please see if the solution would be feasible with the new filter

Comment: Just filter `Promo == 0`, and then same procedure as before

Comment: @sotos, we want to calculate avg for promo == 1 as well, it would be avg of sales of previous non promo weeks